# Strange "Undefined symbols" error?

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ and I got this error:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

my code is this

```
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <iostream>

  class Fraction {
      private:
          int num, den;
      public:
          void set(int n, int d) {num=n; den=d; normalize();}
          int get_num(){return num;}
          int get_den(){return den;}
      private:
          void normalize();

          int gcf(int a, int b);
          int lcm(int a, int b);
  };

  void Fraction::normalize() {
      if (den == 0 || num == 0) {
          num = 0;
          den = 1;
      }

      if (den < 0) {
          num *= -1;
          den *+ -1;
      }

      int n = gcf(num, den);
      num = num / n;
      den = den / n;
  }

  int Fraction::gcf(int a, int b) {
      if (a % b == 0)
          return abs(b);
      else return gcf(b, a % b);
  }
  int Fraction::lcm(int a, int b) {
      return(a / gcf(a, b)) * b;
  }
```

If it helps at all, I am using GCC with the command `g++ -o`.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: You've been told the answer below. But I'm curious, because this program doesn't contain a main function, what did you expect it to do? We're you perhaps trying to create a library, that you could use later in another program? If so then adding a main funciton is not the right thing to do.

Comment: @minitech I doubt I can @ an editor like this properly, but I'm impressed by that edit, just wanted to say :)

Comment: I noticed you wrote `den *+ -1` there instead of `den *= -1`. If that's your actual code, change it too.

Comment: @PaulPRO: Thanks :) It *was* pretty difficult. (And also, you can `@` any single user, but only one.)

Comment: I wonder if smartening up the code too much gives the wrong impression about the OP abilities though. Maybe not in this case but more generally.

Answer (score 4):

Where is your `main` function? Every "ordinary" program in C++ starts from `main` function, which is why the linker is looking for one. You haven't provided it. Hence the error.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you're compiling a source file that doesn't contain a `main` function.  Not every source file has to have `main` defined, but every C++ program needs to have it somewhere, and since you didn't post any other source files I'll assume that this is your only file.  If you try compiling and linking this code, you'll get an error because there is no entry point into the program.

To fix this, either link your code together with a file that contains a `main` function, or add a `main` function to your code, or compile the code without linking it (this depends on your compiler).

Also, you should probably split your code into a .h/.cpp pair.  Typically speaking, classes are defined in header files so that they can be used by other parts of the program, while implementations are left int the .cpp file so that they aren't visible to clients.

Comment: Actually the compiler detected his indentation was so bad that it refused to compile and grabbed the closest error it could find, which was the one he got. Also the first sentence of your answer is a little ambiguous, because every source file doesn't have to have a `main` function.

Answer (score 1):

Add a -c flag when using gcc; it stops the compiler looking for the main function

Answer (score 0):

Almost every C++ function has a `main` function, which tells the computer which part of your code it should do first.  Otherwise, if someone starts your program, where should it begin?  It has a form like below:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    //what should happen when someone runs the program?
    //that goes here
    return 0;  //program all done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think u must change the extension of the file u are using to ".h" instead of ".cpp"

for example :
if this file is named as abc.cpp and u r compiling it the way "gcc abc.cpp" then u must change it to "gcc abc.h" ......

this will instruct the compiler to compile a Header rather than an object file.... :)